# How to calculate the amount of memory needed for a struct with variable length?

Tags: c, malloc, sizeof

Given a struct such as this:

```
struct a {
    int b;
    int c;
    my_t d[];
}
```

What do I have to pass to `malloc` to allocate enough memory for a `struct a` where `d` has `n` elements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
struct a *var = malloc(sizeof(*var) + n*sizeof(var->d[0]))
```

Using the variables for `sizeof` will ensure the size is updated if the types change. Otherwise, if you change the type of `d` or `var` you risk introducing silent and potentially difficult-to-find runtime issues by not allocating enough memory if you forget to update any of the corresponding allocations.

Comment: I like this answer most as it avoids repeating the type name. Repeating type names causes suspicious errors when refactoring.

Comment: I agree in principle but I have to point out that you are repeating a variable name, causing breakage if the variable name is changed, and a member name, causing …

Comment: @pascual better compiler errors when you change things and forget to update rather than silent run-time errors when you change types.

Comment: @Pascal You raise a valid point. The difference in repeating the member name is however that your code fails to compile if you change the members name. If you change the type, nothing fails at compile time, but you might get errors at runtime.

Comment: Good answer, but I think you haven't finished your last.

Answer (score 5):

You can use for instance: `sizeof(struct a) + sizeof(my_t [n])`.

```
typedef int my_t;

struct a {
  int b;
  int c;
  my_t d[];
};

int n = 3;

main(){
  printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof(struct a), sizeof(my_t [n]));
}
```

Result: 8 12

Answer (score 4):

This should be enough:

```
sizeof(a) + n * sizeof(my_t)
```